# Why does this while loop repeat after the user has entered input that is too long?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int stringLength (char *text)
{
  int count = 0;
  while (*text != '\0')
  {
    count++;
    text++;
  }
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  char str[25];
  int length;

  printf("Enter key: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", str);

  length = stringLength(str);

  while (length > 24)
  {
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    length = stringLength(str);
  }
  printf("your string is: %s and its %d long", str, length);
  return 0;
}
```

Cant figure out why the while loop keeps repeating. The point of the code is to just calculate the length of a string (including spaces) and give out the result.

Comment: "the while loop keeps repeating" - which one? What's the output of this code?

Comment: If the length of the string is greater than 24, you've overflowed the buffer.

Comment: Re ”While loop keeps repeating”: That is what they do.

Comment: you must calculate the length of the word outside of the while loop,also it is better to use gets instead of scanf and it is more usefull to use a do - while loop

Comment: Enter a [mre]. That includes not just the program but sample input that reproduces the problem, observed output, and the output that is desired instead. For example, in this case, you could have written “When I enter ‘abcdefghimklnopqrstuvwxyz’, the program repeatedly prints “Enter key: Enter key: Enter key: Enter key: ”, but I want it to print “Enter key: ” once and wait for user input.”

Comment: what behavior are you expecting, and for what input? Also read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Just as a side note: You might want to consider replacing the `while` loop with a `do`...`while` loop. That way, the three lines that are inside the loop won't have to be duplicated outside the loop. This is not related to your problem, though.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf` - also do something to consume the new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from `scanf()`, because it leaves enter on the end. The next function cycle takes the enter as the end of scanning, so it loads nothing. That's why your code keeps cycling at this point, when you pass input longer than 24 characters. You should use `getchar()` right after the `scanf()` input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stringLength (char *text)
{
  int count = 0;
  while (text[count] != '\0')
  {
    count++;
    // text++;
  }
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  char str[25];
  int length;
  do {
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    getchar();
    length = stringLength(str);
  }
  while (length > 24);

  printf("your string is: %s and its %d long", str, length);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: or just use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: `length` is uninitialized at the beginning of the `while` loop. `scanf()` should be given a maximum count of bytes to store into `str`: `scanf("%24[^\n]", str)`. The return value must be tested... This answer needs more work.

Comment: @Chase Well, with `fgets()` you would have delete `\n` at the end.

Comment: `s[strlen(s)] = '\0';`

Answer (score 4):

I assume you’re talking about this loop:

```
while (length > 24)
{
  printf("Enter key: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", str);
  length = stringLength(str);
}
```

The conversion specifier `%[^\n]` reads characters up to, but not including, the next newline character, leaving that newline character in the input stream, which is what you want.  The problem is that `%[` doesn’t skip over leading whitespace, so on the next loop iteration it sees the `\n` from the previous input and immediately returns without reading anything and leaving `str` unchanged.

The quickest way to fix this is to put a leading blank in the format string - `" %[^\n]"`.  That will consume and discard the newline and any other leading whitespace left in the stream from the previous operation.

If’s also a good idea to put an explicit field width on the format so you don’t risk a buffer overflow - `" %24[^\n]"` (need to leave at least one space for the string terminator).

You should also check the return value of `scanf`, which is the number of successful conversions and assignments.  In this case, it should be `1`.  If it’s `0` then you had a *matching failure* and `str` hasn’t been modified.  If it’s `EOF` then you’ve either hit an end-of-file condition (possible if you’re redirecting standard input from a file or piping the result of another program) or there’s an error with the inpit stream itself.

Note that if `length` ever is greater than 24 then you’ve overrun your buffer and have entered the realm of undefined behavior.